# Help with a homework problem involving $\textbf{H}$-conjugate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

My problem is the following:

> Let $\textbf{H}$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Are the following
>   claims true? Why?
>
> a) If the vectors $\textbf{d}_1$ and $\textbf{d}_2$ and vectors
>   $\textbf{d}_2$ and $\textbf{d}_3$ are $\textbf{H}$-conjugate, then
>   also the vectors $\textbf{d}_1$ and $\textbf{d}_3$ are
>   $\textbf{H}$-conjugate.
>
> b) If the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$ of
>    $\textbf{H}$ are $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j,\;$ for $i\neq j$, then the
>   corresponding eigenvectors $\textbf{d}_1, \textbf{d}_2, ...,
>  \textbf{d}_n$ of $\textbf{H}$ are $\textbf{H}$-conjugate among each
>   other.
>
> As a reminder:
>
> The vectors $\textbf{d}_1, ..., \textbf{d}_k$ are
>   $\textbf{H}$-conjugate if they are linearly independent and also:
>
> $$\textbf{d}_i^T \textbf{H}\textbf{d}_j=0,\;\;\forall\; i\neq j.$$

Any hints how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a) holds as stated because it is possible that $\mathbf{d}_3 = \mathbf{d}_1$, so they are not necessarily linearly independent. Is there another condition?

To show $\mathbf{d}_i^T \mathbf{H} \mathbf{d}_j=0$ in part b), note that
$$(\lambda_i \mathbf{d}_i^T) \mathbf{d}_j = \mathbf{d}_i^T \mathbf{H} \mathbf{d}_j = \mathbf{d}_i^T (\lambda_j \mathbf{d}_j).$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! :) in a) no, those are the only conditions given in the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a: Consider $H = I$, the $3 \times 3$ identity, and let the $d_i$  be various standard basis vectors.

Hint for b: Consider 
$$
d_i^T H d_j = d_i \cdot (H d_j) = (Hd_i) \cdot d_j.
$$
[First explain why these equalities hold, of course!]

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Appreciate it!